# Sentence using "hamartia"

Tags: meaning, nouns, literary-techniques

Can any one tell me how to use the word **hamartia** in everyday writing? I have searched a lot but failed to find any sentence using this word. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How to use "hamartia" in daily life: **don't**. The word is a specialized literature term, and you have no reason to use it in everyday conversation (unless you regularly converse about Greek tragedy).

Comment: Hamartia?  Isn't he a pitcher for the Cubs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, "hamartia" can be used more generally to refer to a tragic or fatal flaw. There is also a medical definition that seems to be about abnormal tissue growth (though it is not a tumour). So you *could* probably use "hamartia" when referring to a fatal flaw, but I suspect most people who have not studied medicine or Greek tragedies will not get the reference.

In conclusion: **Don't do it** (unless you want to completely confuse your audience).

I think example will work (since you insisted):

> The web application's hamartia was failing to sanitize input on the user sign-in form. This allowed the database to be compromised and credit card  numbers to be stolen.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamartia I quickly found two examples of usage:

In Greek tragedy, stories that contain a character with a hamartia often follow a similar blueprint. The hamartia, as stated, is seen as an error in judgment or unwitting mistake as applied to the actions of the hero.